# Differential equation $f''-f'-f=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Suppose $f:\Bbb R\rightarrow\Bbb R$ is a solution of $f''-f'-f=1$ and $f(0)=f(k)=0$ for some $k>0$. Then,

1. $f$ has positive and negative values over $(0,k)$
2. $f$ has only positive values over $(0,k)$
3. $f$ has only negative values over $(0,k)$
4. $f=-1$ on $(0,k)$

I have done a similar ques in which the differential equation was $f''-f'-1=0$ and I thought of it like there would be some $c\in (0,k)$ such that $f'(c)=0$ and at c the differential equation will give $f''(c)=1$ and that will be true for all stationary points and therefore there will be no maxima and we can conclude that the funtion will be below the x axis always. But i was not able to do same for this question.

Comment: You already gave the argument why $f$ can not have a positive maximum on the interval. That excludes two of the four options.

Comment: but the differential equation in this question is different right? so i thought that we can have positive maximas as well if the value of f is less than -1 at the stationary point or am i going wrong somewhere?

Comment: At a positive maximum you would have $f''(c) = 1 + f(c) + 0 > 0$, which is not possible.

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: Please don't [delete and repost](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=delete+and+repost).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track. $f$ can not attain a nonnegative maximum at a point $c \in (0, k)$ because then $f(c) \ge 0$ and $f'(c) = 0$, so that
$$
 f''(c) = 1 + f(c) + f'(c) \ge 1 \, ,
$$
which is not possible (the second derivative is always $\le 0$ at a local maximum). That excludes (1) and (2).

(4) is not possible because of the given boundary conditions and the continuity of $f$.